# How do I find the owner of the head in my hand?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-hypixel-skyblock

On Hypixel Skyblock, there is this item called the Raw Soulflow. I think the head looks cool, so I want to copy it.
But, after extensive searching, I can't seem to find out how!
Is there anyway to see the owner of the head in your hand in Minecraft? If you can't in vanilla, is there a mod that lets you?

Answer (score 2):

Using a SkyBlock mod (or any mod that does this tbh), I use a special mod made for editing the official SB wiki - you can take the NBT of an item. Hovering over a Raw Soulflow and taking its NBT gives me this (copied to clipboard):

```
{
id: "minecraft:skull",
Count: 1b,
tag: {
    HideFlags: 254,
    SkullOwner: {
        Id: "0411d14d-f9fb-3395-b96f-b9fb16c47d16",
        Properties: {
            textures: [{
                Value: "eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvODEzZmYwZmJjODE3MWEzMDYyYjZiZDVjYWNmN2FhMmVmZGZlOGRlMzk5NDYyYjJlMDMwYzlkYzljNjAifX19"
            }]
        }
    },
    display: {
        Lore: ["§7Hold and right-click to consume,", "§7gaining §3+1⸎ Soulflow§7!", "", "§a§lUNCOMMON"],
        Name: "§aRaw Soulflow"
    },
    ExtraAttributes: {
        id: "RAW_SOULFLOW"
    }
},
Damage: 3s}
```

The string found at tag -> SkullOwner -> Properties -> textures -> Value is a base64 string which in this case decodes to:

```
{"textures":{"SKIN":{"url":"http://textures.minecraft.net/texture/813ff0fbc8171a3062b6bd5cacf7aa2efdfe8de399462b2e030c9dc9c60"}}}
```

Viewing the url link gives you [image]

which is the skin used for the soulflow item.

Answer (score 0):

Without commands I think your only option is asking the mod developers.

It is not clear what the item is, it might be a regular block added by the mod with custom texture, and not a player head. If the block is indeed implemented as a player head, you have two options:

Place it somewhere (if possible) and then get its NBT with (replace with the actual coordinates):

```
/data get block 125 65 194
```

If it can't be placed, you can drop it on the ground and make sure there are no other items around and then:

```
/data get entity @e[type=item,sort=nearest,limit=1]
```

Comment: They are not talking about any mods, and they don't have commands so they are actually looking for mod recommendations